# why do it show a black screen when i use Uri class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a simple windows store app in c#. When i'm binding my image control to display an image from code- behind, my screen goes black. Anyone know how i can solve the problem?

ImageService Class

```
public class ImageService 
{     

  public Image Image { get; set; }      

    public ImageService()
    {
        var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///assets/Logo.scale-100.png");
        var bmp = new BitmapImage(uri);
        Image.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

XAML file

```
  <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="223"     Margin="394,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="305" Source="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Comment: How is the `ImageService` class even related to the XAML?

Comment: The image control is binded to the Image property in ImageService

Comment: The XAML you are using is not going to do that.

Comment: The datacontext is already set to the ImageService, and then i'm binding the image control to the Image property. Can you explain what else i can do the solve the black screen problem?

Comment: That makes sense. You should have mentioned that the data context is set to `ImageService`. I'll try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class ImageService
{
    public Uri Image { get; set; }
    public ImageService()
    {
        Image = new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/Logo.scale-100.png");
    }
}
```

The `Source` property of an Image is of type `ImageSource` which can be easily replaced by a `Uri`. [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Images in XAML have a built in converter so you can just bind to a Uri, you don't have to create an Image in the service.

Your service isn't implementing INotifyPropertyChanged so if you set your image in your service outside the constructor your view won't update.

I don't see in your code where you are instantiating your Image. Image will be null so when your view loads, the Image will be null resulting in a blank image on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like  this? Cause it still makes the sceen go black.

```
public class ImageService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Uri _uri;

    public Uri Uri
    {
        get { return _uri; }
        set
        {
            _uri = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ImageService()
    {
        Uri = new Uri("ms-appx///assets/Logo.scale-100.png");                                                
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```